# What is DEPENDENT UNION in select_type column from explain command?

Tags: mysql, sql, union, explain

From mysql [ref manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain_select_type): "Second or later SELECT statement in a UNION, dependent on outer query". 
But how UNION query can be dependent on outer query? Can someone give me clear example what does it mean? For instance, in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 /* ! */
)
```

second select statement in union (which itself is subquery) has DEPENDENT UNION select_type and I dont know why, it must be just UNION because it doesn`t depend on anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem in this case is the `IN` operator, because subqueries in an `IN` clause are rewritten as correlated subqueries.

And a correlated subquery will give you a "dependent subquery" or a "dependent union" in case of an union.

See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

> The problem is that, for a statement that uses an IN subquery, the
>   optimizer rewrites it as a correlated subquery. Consider the following
>   statement that uses an uncorrelated subquery:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE t1.a IN (SELECT b FROM t2); The optimizer
>   rewrites the statement to a correlated subquery:
>
> SELECT ... FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.b = t1.a);

Comment: But in `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2` query second statement has `UNION` type, not `DEPENDENT UNION`, why?

Comment: @kirugan Sorry tired, think I finally got it.

Comment: Didn`t know about `IN` behavior, it seems like true. Thanks!

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus please look at my post, what i dont understand is why my query with the union takes forever but without the union is very fast, from what you wrote in both queries it should act as a correlated subquery and take a long time http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133972/mysql-query-with-union-doesnt-use-index

Answer (score 1):

Because MySQL will optimise your sql into Exists Dependent SubQuery.

As below

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE EXISTS (
 (SELECT 1
 WHERE sometable.id = 1) UNION (SELECT 1 WHERE sometable.id = 2)
 )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 9 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.

Comment: Oops, I'm so sorry because I really didn't see the time of this question. Although the question about the inner optimizer principle of MySQL has already had an  accepted answer, I still want to make a supplementary to help somebody else who also see this question in the future to understand it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For me to prevent using `DEPENDENT UNION` by wrapping a plain `SELECT` over `UNIONed SELECTs` will boost the query many times faster(5mins to 5secs):

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `table0` WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM `table1` UNION ALL
...
SELECT id FROM `table10`);
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | table0 |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 8387301 | 100 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | table1 |  | ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | func | 1 | 100 | Using index |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | DEPENDENT UNION | table10 |  | ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | func | 1 | 100 | Using index |

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `table0` WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id FROM `table1` UNION ALL
...
SELECT id FROM `table10`
) AS T);
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | table0 |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 8387301 | 100 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  |  | eq_ref | <auto_distinct_key> | <auto_distinct_key> | 5 | table0.id | 1 | 100 | Using where; Not exists |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  | 646179 | 100 |  |
| 3 | DERIVED | table1 |  | index |  | PRIMARY | 8 |  | 2 | 100 | Using index |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | UNION | table10 |  | index |  | PRIMARY | 8 |  | 638237 | 100 | Using index |

I guess it's related to [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) since [`DEPENDENT typically signifies the use of a correlated subquery`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html), and changing [`subquery_to_derived`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/switchable-optimizations.html#optflag_subquery-to-derived) also might be helpful.